# How to show messages using DetailView on Django

Tags: python, django, detailview

I have Message model and Post model.

I want to show all messages which posted to one post.

I can't think of how to get all messages at certain post using DetailView Class.

How can I do this? or should I create another ListView Class for messages?

[All my code](https://github.com/igor-bond16/django_blog/tree/main/julia_blog)

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template, you can render this as:

```
{% for message in object.message_set.all %}
    {{ message.body }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will thus, for the `Post` object in the context named `object` retrieve all the related `Message`s.

If you want to fetch the data of the related user as well, you can work with a [**`Prefetch`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('message_set', Message.objects.select_related('user'))
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.